# VBA code that copies column from one sheet to another has intermittent "out of memory" error

Tags: excel, vba, out-of-memory

The attached code takes user input from a drop-down list, finds the matching header in another sheet, and copies a column of data from one sheet ("Classification Values") to another ("CLASS_CHECK").

This code causes "out of memory" errors after so many uses, however.

Any ideas how I can improve my code so it doesn't run out of memory?

Thank you!

Code:

---

```
Public headerTitle As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    headerTitle = Range("title").Value
    Debug.Print (headerTitle)
    Call doStuffWithTable
End Sub

Public Sub doStuffWithTable()

    If (headerTitle = "Analog") Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets("CLASS_CHECK").Range("Column").Value = Sheets("Classification Values").Range("Analog").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    ElseIf (headerTitle = "Asic") Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets("CLASS_CHECK").Range("Column").Value = Sheets("Classification Values").Range("Asic").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    ElseIf (headerTitle = "Board Artifacts") Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets("CLASS_CHECK").Range("Column").Value = Sheets("Classification Values").Range("Board").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    ElseIf (headerTitle = "Clock") Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets("CLASS_CHECK").Range("Column").Value = Sheets("Classification Values").Range("Clock").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    ElseIf (headerTitle = "Connector") Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets("CLASS_CHECK").Range("Column").Value = Sheets("Classification Values").Range("Connector").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    ElseIf (headerTitle = "Digital") Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets("CLASS_CHECK").Range("Column").Value = Sheets("Classification Values").Range("Digital").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    ElseIf (headerTitle = "Discrete: Capacitor") Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets("CLASS_CHECK").Range("Column").Value = Sheets("Classification Values").Range("Capacitor").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You really should look into `Select Case` -- much cleaner if you are comparing the same variable over and over.

Comment: How large are the ranges in question?  There's no obvious issues but your code really would benefit from refactoring to remove the duplication.

Comment: Is this your entire code? You are missing an `End If` - so that leads me to believe that it's not. I am somewhat concerned that you might be missing an `EnableEvents = False` somewhere and you are now in an endless loop with your `Worksheet_Change()` event.

Comment: Nope! This is not the entire code. There were just soooo many if statements (I forgot that select case exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would suggest this as one possible refactoring to remove the global variable and the repetition:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngTitle As Range
    Set rngTitle = Me.Range("title")
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rngTitle) Is Nothing Then
        doStuffWithTable rngTitle.Value
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub doStuffWithTable(title)
    Dim rngName As String

    Select Case title
        Case "Analog", "Asic", "Clock", "Connector", "Digital"
            rngName = title
        Case "Board Artifacts"
            rngName = "Board"
        Case "Discrete: Capacitor"
            rngName = "Capacitor"
    End Select

    If Len(rngName) > 0 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CLASS_CHECK").Range("Column").Value = _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Classification Values").Range(rngName).Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Remember that time you gave me a “BIG F FOR FAIL” for using **On Error GoTo Here** in a loop? Lol BIG T FOR THANKS for single handendly internet shaming me which lead to a better understand of loop scripts ;)

Comment: @urdearboy - well I try never to pronounce "Fail" or to shame people, so I will try to work on my people skills ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help, Tim!

Answer (score 0):

You may have an issue with your `Events` as pointed out by @K.Davis. Just toggle off `Events` once and ensure all code that will potentially bring a change is nested inside the `Event` trap.

Your code can be reduced greatly here with use of `Select Case` and `With` block. This also yields significantly better readability which will go a long way in helping you debug your code.

```
Sub TableStuff()

Dim CV As Worksheet
Set CV = Sheets("Classification Values")

Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Sheets("CLASS_CHECK").Range("Column")
        Select Case headerTitle
            Case "Analog"
               .Value = CV.Range("Analog").Value
            Case "Asic"
                .Value = CV.Range("Asic").Value
            Case "Board Artifacts"
                .Value = CV.Range("Board").Value
            Case "Clock"
                .Value = CV.Range("Clock").Value
            Case "Connector"
                .Value = CV.Range("Connector").Value
            Case "Digital"
                .Value = CV.Range("Digital").Value
            Case "Discrete: Capacitor"
                .Value = CV.Range("Capacitor").Value
        End Select
    End With
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```